# How to create NetworkX graph with n nodes (OSMnx compatible) from Shapely object

Tags: python, networkx, polygon, shapely, osmnx

Let's assume we have the following Shapely object:

```
from shapely import geometry

# (lat, long) coordinates
p1 = geometry.Point(-96.87,32.88)
p2 = geometry.Point(-96.77,33.00)
p3 = geometry.Point(-96.67,32.95)
p4 = geometry.Point(-96.65,32.84)
pointList = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p1]

# creat geometric object
p = geometry.Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in pointList])
```

Next we want to create OSMnx compatible NetworkX graph from this polygon. The standard way would be:

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph.graph_from_polygon(p, network_type='drive', simplify=False)
```

But instead of underlining the 'real' road network, I want to generate a 'fake' road network with some density of nodes. Each node should be connected with some number of nearest neighbors. I am not interested in buildings, lakes, etc. I just want a plain NetworkX graph inside of my polygon with some number of randomly distributed nodes and some number of edges that connect those nodes.

```
def f_generate_plain_polygon(p, number_of_nodes, min_number_of_connection_for_each_node):
  ...
```

The generated graph should have some functionality from OSMnx. For example, we could visualize such a graph:

```
ox.plot_graph(G, show=False, close=False, edge_color='black', bgcolor='w', edge_alpha=0.5, node_color='black')
ox.utils_graph.remove_isolated_nodes(G)
```

Here is an example of what function `f_generate_plain_polygon` should generate. It is how polygon looks like:

[image: 1]

And we are adding graph with 60 nodes and at least 3 connections with nearest neighbors for each node:

[image: 2]

If for some reason it is more simple to generate a graph without explicitly specifying a number of nodes but just saying that we want to generate nodes with distance e.g. 0.001 between them it is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible way you can approach your problem.

1. First, in order to use `ox.plot_graph` with your randomly generated graph, you'll need to know what type of graph `ox.plot_graph` takes as input. From the documentation [here](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html?highlight=plot_graph#osmnx.plot.plot_graph), it looks like a `nx.MultiDiGraph` si waht you need (doc [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multidigraph.html)).
2. Next, you can randomly generate a directed graph with `H=nx.gnp_random_graph(100, 0.1, seed=None, directed=True)` for instance. Note that Networkx offers a lot of graph generation functions (see [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generators.html)) so just pick the one that works best for you.
3. In your next step, you can cast your graph from `nx.DiGraph` to `nx.MultiDiGraph` by using `I=nx.MultiDiGraph(H)`.
4. You now have a random `nx.MultiDiGraph`. In order to draw the graph in your polygon you need to associate to each node a `x` and `y` coordinate sampled from within the polygon. I did that using the answer in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802921/using-geopandas-how-to-randomly-select-in-each-polygon-5-points-by-sampling-met)
5. You can then link these positions to your nodes following osmnx syntax by running:

```
for i,node in enumerate(I.nodes(data=True)):
  node[1]['x']=pos[i][0]
  node[1]['y']=pos[i][1]
```

6. As of now, the only thing missing for this to work is associate a `crs` to your random graph. `ox.plot_graph` seems to be requiring it. A simple workaround is to use the one generated for the osmnx graph G in your example.
   `I.graph={'crs':'epsg:4326'}`
7. Finally, you can plot your graph and your polygon (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522395/how-do-i-plot-shapely-polygons-and-objects-using-matplotlib) for how to plot shapely object with matplotlib):

```
x,y = p.exterior.xy
fig,ax=ox.plot_graph(I,show=False, close=False, edge_color='black', bgcolor='w', edge_alpha=0.5, node_color='black')
ox.utils_graph.remove_isolated_nodes(I)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xlim([-96.9,-96.6])
ax.set_ylim([32.82,33.02])

plt.show()
```

[image]

See full code here:

```py
from shapely import geometry
from shapely.geometry import Point
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox

# (lat, long) coordinates
p1 = geometry.Point(-96.87,32.88)
p2 = geometry.Point(-96.77,33.00)
p3 = geometry.Point(-96.67,32.95)
p4 = geometry.Point(-96.65,32.84)
pointList = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p1]

# creat geometric object
p = geometry.Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in pointList])

H=nx.gnp_random_graph(100, 0.1, seed=None, directed=True) #step 2
I=nx.MultiDiGraph(H) #step 3

def random_point_in_shp(shp):  #step 4
    within = False
    while not within:
        x = np.random.uniform(shp.bounds[0], shp.bounds[2])
        y = np.random.uniform(shp.bounds[1], shp.bounds[3])
        within = shp.contains(Point(x, y))
    return [x,y]
pos=[random_point_in_shp(p) for _ in range(100)]

for i,node in enumerate(I.nodes(data=True)): #step 5 
  node[1]['x']=pos[i][0]
  node[1]['y']=pos[i][1]

I.graph={'crs':'epsg:4326'} #step 6

x,y = p.exterior.xy #step 7
fig,ax=ox.plot_graph(I,show=False, close=False, edge_color='black', bgcolor='w', edge_alpha=0.5, node_color='black')
ox.utils_graph.remove_isolated_nodes(I)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xlim([-96.9,-96.6])
ax.set_ylim([32.82,33.02])

plt.show()
```

### EDIT: Example with a 3-neighbors graph (60 nodes, 180 edges)

The core of the process is the same. The difference comes from creating the node position before the graph. And then, use the lypysal `weights.KNN` function to connect nodes with their 3 closest neighbors as in the link you provided in comments ([here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/auto_examples/geospatial/plot_points.html)). The graph can then be turned into a `nx.MultiDiGraph` and the rest is the same.

```py
from shapely import geometry
from shapely.geometry import Point
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
import libpysal

# (lat, long) coordinates
p1 = geometry.Point(-96.87,32.88)
p2 = geometry.Point(-96.77,33.00)
p3 = geometry.Point(-96.67,32.95)
p4 = geometry.Point(-96.65,32.84)
pointList = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p1]

# creat geometric object
p = geometry.Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in pointList])

def random_point_in_shp(shp):  #step 4
    within = False
    while not within:
        x = np.random.uniform(shp.bounds[0], shp.bounds[2])
        y = np.random.uniform(shp.bounds[1], shp.bounds[3])
        within = shp.contains(Point(x, y))
    return [x,y]

N_nodes=60
pos=[random_point_in_shp(p) for _ in range(60)]

#create 3-neighbor graph
kd=libpysal.cg.KDTree(np.array(pos))
knn3=libpysal.weights.KNN(kd, k=3)
knn_graph = knn3.to_networkx()
K=nx.MultiDiGraph(knn_graph)


for i,node in enumerate(K.nodes(data=True)): #step 5 
  node[1]['x']=pos[i][0]
  node[1]['y']=pos[i][1]

K.graph={'crs':'epsg:4326'} #step 6

x,y = p.exterior.xy #step 7
fig,ax=ox.plot_graph(K,show=False, close=False, edge_color='black', bgcolor='w', edge_alpha=0.5, node_color='black')
ox.utils_graph.remove_isolated_nodes(K)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xlim([-96.9,-96.6])
ax.set_ylim([32.82,33.02])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. Is it possible to generate graph where each node is connected e.g. only with nearest 3 neighbors? It looks like function `gnp_random_graph` does not have such functionality. I looked at this documentation: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/auto_examples/geospatial/plot_points.html where authors created 3-nearest neighbor graph but I am not sure if it is possible to add it to approach you suggested.

Comment: It's also possible to do that. See edit of my answer